# Jconsole not working on linux machine

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jconsole

My Java Application is deployed on WebLogic Server. I want to monitor my application to see whether its leaking any memory.
 When I run jconsole on my local machine I just have to write jconsole on command prompt, but when I am connected to a linux machine through putty and running this command it just wait for long.
 How can I run JConsole for this linux machine.
 I also tried to run it remotely but it also not working on command prompt I wrote jconsole host:port then it asks for userid and password but nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use VisualVM if you can, but you need to be able to display X-Windows applications to have any chance of displaying JConsole or VisualVM. Try running `xterm &` from your console. Until that works, you won't get any graphical application to work.

To connect remotely you need to setup JMX to allow this. You can turn off security to start with, or a better solution is to setup and username and password.

Comment: if xterm not work then what?? In my case it is not working and telling me - xterm Xt error: Can't open display: %s
                                           xterm:  DISPLAY is not set

Comment: Without a graphical display, you need remote access. I would start by trying to turn off JMX security (temporarily) to see if you can get this to work.